# Remove non alphanumeric chars but keep decimals in C# string

Tags: c#, regex, char

I need to convert this:

> 7.5kg (estimate). 2,4 kilos (total?%/="º).,¿#@--__

into this:

> 7.5kg estimate 2,4 kilos total

Things to note:

- remove non alphanumeric but keep numbers
- numbers can have dot or comma notation
- numbers can be integers or decimals

**EDIT**

I´m wondering that I need to negate this regex `@"\d+[\.\,]?\d*` (that matches integers and decimals) and then remove non alphanumeric on the result. Not sure if that´s possible in a single Regex.

A regex would be ok.
C# code messing around with chars would be ok as well.

**EDIT 2**

I did a little research based on Keith answer to better understand it:

[image]

Comment: well, have a go at doing it, if you have any problems, come back and ask a specific question

Comment: Well, I´ve been trying hard with no success. That´s why I´m asking here. I need some kind of "match everything except things matching `@"\d+[\.\,]?\d*"`)"

Comment: alternative with negative lookahead, but might not handle all edge cases [`(?![.,]\d)[^0-9a-zA-Z ]+`](https://regex101.com/r/wqYSWC/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :-

```
public static string Filter(string s)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"(\d\.\d|\d,\d|[0-9a-zA-Z]|\s)+");
    var matches = regex.Matches(s);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var match in matches) sb.Append(match);
    return sb.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Filter("7.5kg (estimate). 2,4 kilos (total?%/=\"º).,¿#@--__"));
}
```

[image]